# Javascript for input file button in order to notify that file upload is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input, erb

I am currently styling the input file buttons of my website. So far I have changed the opacity of the native input file so it doesn't display and gave it a z-index of 2 so the button is still clickable. 
The problem is that, without the native behavior of the input file, I have no indication of when the file has finished its upload.
How can I add a JS/JQUERY that displays a little :

```
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
```

next to my button when the file upload is finished.

Here's what my html looks like :

```
 <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
   <div class="upload-file-container">
      <%= f.file_field :licencepicture, id: "myFileInput" %>
      <div id="fileName"></div>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you provide your js codes?

Comment: what do you mean ? I am actually looking for some JS to do that because I didnt manage to writte anything good myself

Comment: Can you post what you wrote so we can help you? We're not just about writing code for people

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get the results of upload file from input file button, you can get it using the class FileReader. With that you can see whether your file was uploaded to you input type file.

Html:

```
<input id="fileInpt" type="file"/>
<br/>
<img id="imagePreview" alt="image preview" />
```

JQuery:

```
 $("#fileInpt").on("change", function(){

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            //With this e object you can get anything you want from input
            //type file. The content of uploaded file, for example:
            //e.target.result;
            $("#imagePreview").attr("src", e.target.result);

            alert("Load content is finished!");
        }
    }
});
```

However, if you would like to see the results of upload you have to work with ajax using jquery or plain javascript.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { id : menuId },
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( msg );
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the file upload completes over ajax, you'll have a success callback, add it in there, like this (this code is kinda rough, but should give you an idea of what to aim at):

```
$("#myFileInput").on("change", function(e){
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(myMethod, myURL, true);
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if(xhr.status === 200) {
      $("#myFileInput").after('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
    }
    else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
});
```

Comment: I dont see exactly why I need AJAX here. I am not writting any lines of AJAX to get my file. Everything is taken care of by rails I think ? (I updated the post)

Comment: Well, if you're not doing a full page reload, or an iframe reload, ajax is being used somewhere. The idea nonetheless is to add `$("#myFileInput").after('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');` in the success handler after the file is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    realInputField = $('#myFileInput')
    realInputField.change(function() {
      $('#fileName').append( "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>" )
    });
});
```